# Anonymous function in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I want to write the following anonymous function in MATLAB.

I have a piecewise function. I want to turn this into a single expression. How can this be accomplished in MATLAB ?

$$f(x,t) = 
\begin{cases}
20e^{-4x^2} & \text{if $0 \leq t \leq T/2,$} \\
0 & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 4):

```
T = 1.0;
f = @(x,t) (0 <= t & t <= T/2)*20*exp(-4*x.^2) + 0.0;
x = linspace(0,1,100);
plot(x, f(x,T/4), x, f(x,T))
legend('t=T/4','t=T')
```

Comment: How can you initialise T to be 1 ? T can be anything.

Comment: Set T to whatever you want. I just gave an example.

Comment: To enable vectorization with respect to t, you'll need `f = @(x,t) (0 <= t & t <= T/2)*20*exp(-4*x.^2) + 0.0;`, that is, logical and without short-circuiting (& instead of &&).

Comment: @cos_theta Thanks I didnt know this, I updated the answer.